# Generics for repeated task with associated data - Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, generics, nsdictionary

I've been trying to wrap my mind around a seemingly simple task, but keep getting nowhere.

My goal is to create a user-choice flow.
Let's say I have a list of food-related questions like :

```
What is your favourite breakfast? What do you have for dinner? How do you like     
your meat cooked? Whats your favourite spaghetti sauce? e.t.c.
```

And a set of reply options for each question

```
Q1: <<Pancakes|Waffles>>, Q2: <<Steak|Spaghetti>>, Q3: <<Raw|Welldone>>, Q4: <<Bolognese|Simple cheese>>
```

How do i load a next question with a set of reply options depending on the users choice in the previous question? But the main trouble is how do i make it generic and data-driven - without the need for a bunch of conditionals.

I've been trying to work with `Arrays`, `NSDictionaries`, `NSRegularExpressions` but can't come up with a proper logical solution.

Any insights are very appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So your question is basically which data structure to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to dictionaries would be a custom class.  I think it improves readability but you may have your own opinion.

```
class Question {
    var ask: String
    var answers: [String]

    var nextQuestions = [Question?]()

    init(question: String, ans: [String]) {
        self.ask = question
        self.answers = ans
    }

    func nextQuestion(answer: String) -> Question? {
        var result: Question? = nil
        if let index = find(self.answers, answer) {
            result = self.nextQuestions[index]
        }
        return result
    }
}

// Set up your test data
let q1 = Question(question: "What is your favourite breakfast", ans: ["Pancakes", "Waffles"])
let q2 = Question(question: "What do you have for dinner", ans: ["Steak", "Spaghetti"])
let q3 = Question(question: "How do you like your meat cooked", ans: ["Raw", "Welldone"])
let q4 = Question(question: "What's your favourite spaghetti sauce", ans: ["Bolognese", "Simple cheese"])

// This is quick and dirty.
// It would be better to have a func to hide the implementation.
q1.nextQuestions.append(q2)
q1.nextQuestions.append(q2)
q2.nextQuestions.append(q3)
q2.nextQuestions.append(q4)

// Pretend "Spaghetti" was the answer for q2
var theQuestion = q2
let userAnswer = "Spaghetti"

if let another = theQuestion.nextQuestion(userAnswer) {
    theQuestion = another
}
```

Comment: I would agree with this method, but I would use a dictionary where the keys are the answers to the current question and values are the follow up question for that answer. But other than that +1.

Comment: @MikeAtNobel Well, that's exactly what I proposed, isn't it?

Comment: Answer edited for better style: let the question be responsible for identifying the next one.

Comment: @Darko But you didn't mention a Question class directly. And what I was suggesting was more along the lines of what Phillp Mills proposed. I was just saying that instead of an answers array and nextQuestion array, he could just make a dictionary like [String:Question] to have the answer pull the next question.

Comment: @MikeAtNobel - I clearly wrote a definition of a dict with two custom classes "Question" and "Answer". But you are right, I didn't mention it directly...

Comment: @Darko and Phillip Mills thank you both for such a thoughtful input! i'll try the codes out very soon.

Answer (score 2):

An obvious solution would be a dictionary of questions which holds another dictionary of related answers and their possible (follow up) questions. Something like:

```
[Question: [Answer:Question]]
```

The question in the second dictionary then refers (recursive) to a question in the first one.